# The set_password() method isn't encrypting the password in a custom Django user model

Tags: django, python-3.x, encryption, hash

I am saving these details in a custom user model stored in MySQL, but the password is not getting encrypted; it is being saved in plain text.

```
def regauth(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAuth(data=request.POST)
        # user_form = UserAuth(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                messages.info(request, 'inside try')
                user = form.save()
                user.set_password(form.password)
                user.save()    
                return redirect('login_url')
            except:
                messages.info(request, 'inside exception')
                return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {'form': form})    
    else:
        user_form = UserAuth()
    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {'form': user_form})
```

> Forms.py

```
class UserAuth(forms.ModelForm):
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
  class Meta:
      model = RegAuth
      fields = "__all__"
```

How can I make sure the `set_password()` method gets called properly to encrypt the password?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Saving with commit=False gets you a model object, then you can add your extra data and save it.

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False) # <---
    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))  # <---
    user.save()    
...
```

Comment: Not decrypting password and not saving plain text also in database

Comment: How do you define the variable  `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings file should be some like this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourApp.RegAuth'`

Comment: Thank u Jacek , now its working. i change AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL to AUTH_USER_MODEL and
 a = form.save()
                a.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get(a.password))
                a.save()

                return redirect('login_url')

Comment: @JayeshSakare Great! but `form.cleaned_data.get(a.password)` is wrong!  `cleaned_data` is a Python dictionary and an attribute of the form object. As a Python dictionary, you can access its values by `form.cleaned_data[‘field’]` or `form.cleaned_data.get(‘field’)`

Comment: @JayeshSakare Please accept the answer if it was helpful. I leave you a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to do it.

Comment: in above point whatever u have written , i applied to my code but only (form.cleaned_data.get(a.password)) is working fine..& i accepted ur answer tq..